# SQL Alternative to Cursor when Manipulating values of related rows

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I have a simple table that stores stock levels. ie.

```
ID int PK
LocationID int
StockLevel real
```

There could be multiple rows in this table for each location ie:

```
ID | LocationID | StockLevel
----------------------------
1  |      1     | 100
2  |      1     | 124
3  |      2     | 300
```

In this example its trivial to see that 224 units exist at location 1.

When I come to decrement the stock level at location 1 I am using
a cursor to iterate over all rows at where LocationID is 1 and using some simple
logic decide whether the stock available at the current row will satisfy the passed in
decrement value. If the row has sufficient quantity to satisfy the requirement I decrement the rows value and break out of the cursor, and end the procedure, however if the row doesnt have sufficient quantity available I decrement its value to zero and move to the next row and try again (with the reduced quantity)

Its quite simple and works ok, but the inevitable question is: Is there a way of performing
this RBAR operation without a cursor?? I have attempted to search for alternatives but even wording
the search criteria for such an operation is painful!

Thanks in advance
Nick

ps. I am storing data in this format because each row also contains other columns that are unique, and hence cant simply be aggregated into one row for each location.

pps. Cursor Logic as requested (where '@DecrementStockQuantityBy' is the quantity that we need
to reduce the stock level by at the specified location):

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

   IF CurrentRowStockStockLevel >= @DecrementStockQuantityBy
   BEGIN

          --This row has enough stock to satisfy decrement request
        --Update Quantity on the Current Row by @DecrementStockQuantityBy   
          --End Procedure       
          BREAK

   END

   IF CurrentRowStockStockLevel < @DecrementStockQuantityBy
   BEGIN

         --Update CurrentRowStockStockLevel to Zero
         --Reduce @DecrementStockQuantityBy by CurrentRowStockStockLevel
         --Repeat until @DecrementStockQuantityBy is zero or end of rows reached

   END

   FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor

END
```

Hope this is clear enough? Let me know if further/better explanation is required.
Thanks

Comment: Please include your cursor logic.

Comment: Actually: we should see the **definition** of the cursor (the `SELECT` statement it deals with) - not how you fetch values from it......

Answer (score 0):

You are correct sir a simple update statement can help you in this scenario I'm still trying to find a legitimate use for a cursor or while that I can't solve with CTE or set based.

After looking a little deeper into your question I will also propose an alternate solution:

```
Declare @LocationValue int = 1,@decimentvalue int = 20


with temp (id,StockLevel,remaining) as (
select top 1 id, Case when StockLevel - @decimentvalue >0 then
           StockLevel = StockLevel - @decimentvalue 
         else 
           StockLevel = 0
         end,  @decimentvalue - StockLevel
from simpleTable st
where st.LocationID  = @LocationValue
union all 
select top 1 id, Case when StockLevel - t.remaining >0 then
           StockLevel = StockLevel -t.remaining 
         else 
           StockLevel = 0
         end,  t.remaining - StockLevel
from simpleTable st
where st.LocationID  = @LocationValue
and exists (select remaining from temp t
            where st.id <> t.id
            group by t.id
            having min(remaining ) >0) )

update st
set st.StockLevel = t.StockLevel
from simpleTable st
inner join temp t on t.id = st.id
```

Comment: Hi Jstead, thanks for the answer. This solution doesn't work for me though as the 2nd and subsequent rows that get updated should be updated by a reduced amount. (eg. The difference between '@decimentvalue' and the amount that was successfully taken from the previous row.) Whereas in your example all rows are decremented equally.

Comment: Thanks again for the assistance Jstead. I am getting: Recursive references are not allowed in subqueries. when I run this. Any ideas?